# Python: Is there a more efficient way to convert int value of months?

Tags: python

I have a list of integers `[1, 2...40, 41...]` that represent months of a few years. i.e. `1` is January of year 1, `13` is January of year 2, and so on. When trying to convert into just the month integer (all Januarys to `1`, etc.) I'm using `month_int % 12` but it turns December into `0`. I wrote the following small block to catch the Decembers but was wondering if there's a more efficient way?

```
for month_int in month_list:
    if not(bool(month_int % 12)):
        # Dec exception here
    else:
        # work as normal
```

Basically, I want to change lists like this:

```
[1, 2...12, 13, 14, 15...]
[1, 2...12, 1, 2, 3...]
```

Comment: What does `0` represent? You might just want `(month_int - 1) % 12`. Add `1` again if you want to go back to 1-based numbers. I.e. `(month_int - 1) % 12 + 1`.

Comment: @smarx sorry, the list starts at 1, I'll update the post to reflect that. But I think what you're saying would still work in this scenario

Comment: You can use `month_list = [(i-1) % 12 + 1 for i in month_list]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fodma1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2419215/fodma1)'s answer has you covered, but you can do it even shorter:

```
month = month % 12 or 12

>>> l = [1, 2, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> [m % 12 or 12 for m in l]
[1, 2, 12, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Good solution as well! Is there any particular reason to use yours over @fodma1's in terms of efficiency?

Comment: This should be more efficient, as it only does a single modulo operation in 11 out of 12 cases, while the other solution always does a subtraction, a modulo and an addition. But None of those should ever be expensive enough to influence your decision. Pick whichever you deem more readable.

Answer (score 3):

You are indexing from 1 instead of zero. What you can do is subtract 1 and then add 1 to the remainder again:

```
month = (month - 1) % 12 + 1
```

Comment: Yep, I knew it was a simple fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since there are more months that aren't December it would be slightly more efficient to have that condition first e.g.

```
for month_int in month_list:
if (bool(month_int % 12)):
    # normal
else:
    # December
```

Since it will only move to the else once every 12 iterations then.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wrote that conditional block really fast and wasn't paying much attention